# emails from postfix are marked as spam on gmail

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta

i'm trying to send mails from my postfix dedicated server to gmail and it is always marked as SPAM. Other mail servers accept my mails.

**log from /var/log/mail.log**:

```
Jun 27 03:30:20 ns3026153 postfix/cleanup[11495]: 9FFE838154D: message-id=<20200627013020.9FFE838154D@mateuszji.net>
Jun 27 03:30:20 ns3026153 postfix/qmgr[11480]: 9FFE838154D: from=<admin@mateuszji.net>, size=9513, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 27 03:30:21 ns3026153 postfix/smtp[11904]: 9FFE838154D: to=<my_email_address@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.253.120.26]:25, delay=0.68, delays=0.01/0/0.36/0.31, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1593221421 q12si17092032wrm.456 - gsmtp)
Jun 27 03:30:21 ns3026153 postfix/qmgr[11480]: 9FFE838154D: removed
```

**my postfix main.cf**:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/mateuszji.net.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/mateuszji.net.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
# custom
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
tls_high_cipherlist=EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mateuszji.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, mateuszji.net,  localhost.$mydomain
mydomain = mateuszji.net
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

**DNS Record on CloudFlare**:

`TXT v=spf1 ip4:{server_ip_address} mx -all`

Anyone have some idea how to fix it?

Comment: you have to look at the headers on the email in the spam folder

Comment: theres generally a lot of dns work to do as well

Comment: @DanielA.White can you explain me what should I do?

Comment: theres plenty of sites that can help you - but without details in the email headers, we can't do much to help you

Comment: @DanielA.White I've put full header from gmail on pastebin, because it is too long for topic - https://pastebin.com/zSaJ5gEJ

Comment: it looks like your configuration is not spf compliant - theres plenty of tools out there that can help you wtih that

Comment: now I've added include:_spf.google.com to my DNS record. Gmail said SPF:PASS, but it is still marked as SPAM.

Comment: have a look at tools like mxtoolbox.com email is hard and very case by case.